# Regex not matching regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am currently working at a project involving regex in php. I wanted to know why or how can I get this recursive regular expression to work in PHP:

```
/\(((?:(?:[^?+*{}()[\]\\|]+|\\.|\[(?:\^?\\.|\^[^\\]|[^\\^])(?:[^\]\\]+|\\.)*\]|\((?:\?[:=!]|\?<[=!]|\?>)?(?1)??\)|\(\?(?:R|[+-]?\d+)\))(?:(?:[?+*]|\{\d+(?:,\d*)?\})[?+]?)?|\|)*)\)/
```

It should match this text (for example):

```
{{"test":"([a-f0-9]{32})"},{"test2":"([a-z]{3})"}}
```

And the given results should be an array with:

- `[a-f0-9]{32}`
- `[a-z]{3}`

**EDIT:**

```
$from = '{{"test":"([a-f0-9]{32})"},{"test2":"([a-z]{3})"}}'; 
preg_match_all("/(((?:(?:[^?+*{}()[]\\|]+|\\.|[(?:\^?\\.|\^[^\]|[^\\^])(?:[^]\]+‌​|\\.)*]|((?:\?[:=!]|\?<[=!]|\?>)?(?1)??)|(\?(?:R|[+-]?\d+)))(?:(?:[?+*]|\{\d+‌​(?:,\d*)?\})[?+]?)?|\|)*))/", $from, $output_array, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE); 
var_dump($output_array);
```

Comment: can you show us, what you tried in php?

Comment: Can you provide test cases that require the use of recursions ?

Comment: Throw your own title into google and there is your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question and don't add code/information in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why this complex?

```
preg_match ('/\:"\((.*)\)"/', $search, $ matches);
```

It seems you just want the values between `:"(` and `)"`?

The matches are in $matches.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Because I wanted to match all regex in string "from", but your answer makes me think at an alternative. I wanted to use it for this: http://prntscr.com/961c6c

Comment: I want to use each regex from left and get each value and then use it in right textarea using $1, $2, etc...

Comment: @MariusEugenCirciu, seems like you have a valid json, then why do you need regexp? Decode json, change it how you need it, encode.

Comment: I have edited my post and it should work in this way. I added `:` in regex. Only if your regex in $from contains the sequence `:"(` or `")` it wont work.

Comment: @radioheaded, because each json has id's (matching 32 chars from a-f0-9) and i want to replace entire json with json from right and then use regex from left into right side (as i said $1, $2, etc). I want to make it simplier but i don't know how...

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you want?

Comment: @Ben, take a look at this screenshot (http://prntscr.com/961jje) 
1. I have a text that matches first json 
2. Both regex from first json get 2 ids (of 32 chars from a-f0-9). 
3. I replace both ids in second json
4. With second json i replace it in text where first json was matched.

I know is complicated to understand (and more to explain it)

Comment: If it's this complex you should decode the json. Handle complex logic in php and json encode it again.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, I will try doing so :)